# How to check if all elements in array are even in Java

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

How i can check if all elements in the arrays are even or odd?
For the evens I try with this:

```
public boolean isEvens(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length;i++) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But there is error......
Thnx in advance !

Comment: Reading what your code does: i = 0, if i is even, return true, otherwise return false, ... - it shouldn't be too hard to see the problem(s) with that.

Comment: `i % 2 == 0` is checking if index is even or odd.

Comment: You should not compare i%2 as i is index you should compare array[i]%2.
Secondly you should not return boolean value in this way . you should return false from inside the loop if array[i] is odd , otherwise simply return true after the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for an odd element, if not present then all are even.

```
public boolean isEvens (int[] array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: He wants to check array elements and not `i` itself

Comment: @Cargeh yes you are right, missed out that details, answer updated

Answer (score 8):

- You should check the array elements, not the array indices.
- You shouldn't return `true` before checking all the elements of the array.
- You can use a counter to count the number of odds or evens, or a boolean to determine if there are any odds or evens.

For example:

```
public boolean allEven(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

To check whether all are even or all are odd:

```
public boolean allEvenOrAllOdd(int[] array) {
    boolean hasOdd = false;
    boolean hasEven = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            hasEven = true;
            if (hasOdd) { // has both odds and evens
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            hasOdd = true;
            if (hasEven) { // has both odds and evens
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true; // either all elements are odd or all elements are even
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I was also thinking people only post the solution, without explanation of why is the poster wrong and what should they correct.

Comment: Your second example seems needlessly complicated - `if (array[i] % 2 != array[i-1] % 2)` or you can start off setting hasEven based on the first element and then you still just need a single if-statement.

Comment: @Lino `for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) if (array[i] % 2 != array[i-1] % 2) return false; return true;`.

Answer (score 8):

Since java 8 it's a good practice to reduce code by using lambdas:

For even:

```
return Arrays.stream(array).allMatch( i -> i % 2 == 0);
```

for odd:

```
return Arrays.stream(array).allMatch( i -> i % 2 == 1);
```

Comment: you can omit the `array.length == 0 ? false :` part

Answer (score 0):

You want to be comparing array elements at index `i`, and not `i` itself.
The check should be `if (array[i] % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code to for reference use a[i]

```
  public static void isEvens() {
    int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length;i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
           System.out.println("Even");
        }
        else {
           System.out.println("Odd");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would recommend using recursion for it, because with recursion the run time will be less than with loops, also it's some lines of code.
>   I made a code for doing this but with c#, I will post it below, it might help you, because the syntax in java is so similar to the syntax of c#.

```
public static bool isAllEvens(int[] a, int index)
    {
        if (index == 0 && a[index] % 2 == 0) return true;
        else
        {
            if (a[index] % 2 == 0)
                return true && isAllEvens(a, index - 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

> And to call this function just call it with two parameters(array, and array.length - 1 which is the last index).

**Here is an example for calling this function**:

```
        int[] a = new int[4];
        a[0] = 8; a[1] = 4; a[2] = 8; a[3] = 8;
        Console.WriteLine(isAllEvens(a, a.Length - 1));
```